# php search query for multiple inputs into one field

Tags: php, sql

I just want to input mobile_no1 and mobile_no2  and want to search in mobile_no.
I have a table with mobileno, cusname, etc,
I want to search mobile number by giving first and last digits of mobile number.
How?

```
    $table_name ='search1_ts1';
    if(isset($_POST['tablename']) && !empty($_POST['tablename'])){
        $table_name =$_POST['tablename'];
    }   
    $search_query='SELECT mobile_no, fname, cus_name '.
                  'FROM $table_name '.
                  "WHERE mobile_no LIKE 'mobile_no1%' ".
                    "AND mobile_no LIKE '%mobile_no2'";
    $conditionsql="";
    if(isset($_POST['mobile_no1'], $_POST['mobile_no2']) && 
           !empty($_POST['mobile_no1'])) {
        $conditionsql.=" mobile_no1 like '%" . $_POST['mobile_no1'] . "%'";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['mobile_no2']) && !empty($_POST['mobile_no2'])){
        $conditionsql.=" and mobile_no2 like '%" . $_POST['mobile_no2'] . "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to get the results which will have start (input 1) and end  (input 2) numbers of the given search

```
$table_name ='search1_ts1';
                        if(isset($_POST['tablename']) && !empty($_POST['tablename'])){
                            $table_name =$_POST['tablename'];
                        }   
                        $search_query="SELECT mobile_no, fname, cus_name FROM $table_name";
                        $conditionsql="";

                        if(isset($_POST['mobile_no1']) && !empty($_POST['mobile_no1'])) {
                            $conditionsql.=" mobile_no1 like '%" . addslashes($_POST['mobile_no1']) . "'";
                        }
                        if(isset($_POST['mobile_no2']) && !empty($_POST['mobile_no2'])){
                            $conditionsql.=" and mobile_no2 like '" .addslashes( $_POST['mobile_no2'] ). "%'";

            }


$search_query = $search_query+'where'+$conditionsql;
```

Comment: I didn't get the result, attached whole page pls check and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the LEFT() and RIGHT() functions.

I am not 100% sure what you're trying to match but this one will match first digit of mobile_no1 and last digit of mobile_no2 in the mobile_no field.

Try this:

```
$searcy_query = "SELECT mobile_no, fname, cus_name FROM $table_name 
                 WHERE mobile_no LIKE CONVERT(CHAR(1),LEFT(mobile_no1,1))+'%'
                 AND mobile_no like '%'+CONVERT(CHAR(1),RIGHT(mobile_no2,1))";
```